# How to insert an item into an array at a specific index in c#?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, indexing

I have 2 text boxes `(txt1, txt2)`, 2radio button `(rb1, rb2)`, 2 numericupdown box`(nud1,nud2)` & `combo box`. 
I want to store the data from the above in an array, in the named places. array name is mycode.
*example:*
`rb1 = mycode[3], combobox=mycode[0], txt1=mycode[6]`....etc
Eventually I want to concatnate some of the named idexes in my array. And show in the message box
*example:*
my code is `mycode[3] + mycode[7]`
how to do it?
but I don't know best optios is to do this arry, list or any other?

Comment: if you don't want to make a class to hold ytour values, a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) might be an option

Comment: @timur i don't know how to use dictionary to this work. I'll try Google and learn.

Comment: the documentation page I liked has an example. It's a bit longer than you need, but it demonstrates the point. Maybe have a look at that and see if it fits your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for??

```cs
myCode[0] = myValue
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an array, you can create an empty array like this;

```
var arr = Object[7] //This allows you to add different data types, and 7 sets the array length to hold 7 items
arr[0] = txt1.text;
arr[1] = txt2.text;
```

You can concatenate this way:

```
Console.Write($" my code is {arr[1]} + {arr[2]}")
```

Comment: how to add string values & int decimal  values (numericupdownbox) in to a single array?

Comment: I have updated the answer to make use of an object array. Note that you cannot sum up a string and a decimal without an explicit conversion

Answer (score 0):

Array is too primitive for your needs. as @timur suggested, you can create a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` which your "TKey" is `string` and your "TValue" is `object`. you can use it like this:

```
// Create a new dictionary of objects, with string keys.
//
Dictionary<string, object> mycode= 
    new Dictionary<string, object>();

// Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no 
// duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
mycode.Add("txt1", "Hello");
mycode.Add("rb1", 2);
```

you can use actual control references instead of their names as string. all of controls are inherited from `Control` class. so you can use `Dictionary<Control, object>`.

here i provide you a simple exapmle with a form that have a TextBox (textBox1), a NumericUpDown (numericUpDown1) and a Button (button1).

```
        Dictionary<Control, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<Control, object>();

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myDictionary.ContainsKey((Control)sender))
                myDictionary[(Control)sender] = ((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;
            else
                myDictionary.Add((Control)sender, ((NumericUpDown)sender).Value);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(numericUpDown1))
                textBox1.Text = ((decimal)myDictionary[numericUpDown1]).ToString();
        }
```

with this approach you must do a lot of cast and you must be careful.

Comment: what are you mean "openWith"?  And how to concatnate Dictionary objects?

Comment: "openWith" was typo. Dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs. it is not a single KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>, so you can add as many  key-value pairs as you like.